# How to insert curl response values into database

Tags: php

I generated AWBNoSeries with help of below code in [link](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/awb2.php) :

**ReturnMessage":"Successful","ReturnCode":100,"AWBNoGenRequestedDateTime":"20-11-2018 11:46:35","BatchID":"UQpyj61049","AWBNoSeries":["14104918100000","14104918100001",**

```
<?php

$data = 
array (
  'BusinessUnit' => 'ECOM',
  'ServiceType' => 'FORWARD',
  'BatchID'   =>   'UQpyj61049',
);


$url = "http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/GetAWBNumberGeneratedSeries";
$data = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json", 
    "XBKey: QGfMthH1",
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response;

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4"); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ecomexpress_awb"); 

//$id = $_POST['id']; 

$sql = $con->query('INSERT INTO ecomexpress_awb(awb) values ()'); 

mysqli_close($con); 

?>
```

Now i need to save these below AWBNoSeries in mysql table **ecomexpress_awb** & in column **awb** with **each AWBNo in different row**....

14104918100000","14104918100001","14104918100002","14104918100003"

I am not getting what i need to pass in **values ()** in above query....

Comment: Parse the JSON, access the array, loop over the elements and ... insert into your database.

Comment: @misorude Thanks for reply, i will follow your steps, if you give me code for that, it will be really helpfull ,  so to parse i need to convert to `string` right instead of `array` ?

Comment: No, the response you get from `curl_exec` is already a string. So next step is to decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop through all of the values found and add each one to the database. For this, I have had good experience with using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Using this method, you can set up the statement and send it to the SQL server one time, then just change the parameter(s) you provide to the query (in this case, AWBNo and AWBNoGenRequestedDateTime), and execute for each value. The full code would look something like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$data =
array (
  'BusinessUnit' => 'ECOM',
  'ServiceType' => 'FORWARD',
  'BatchID'   =>   'UQpyj61049',
);


$url = "http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/GetAWBNumberGeneratedSeries";
$data = json_encode($data);


$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "XBKey: QGfMthH1",
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
//we know this is working, no need to echo data
//echo $curl_response;

// justin code start

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "your_password", "do_management4");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$parsedData = json_decode($curl_response, true); //true: preserve associative arrays

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ecomexpress_awb(awb, created_at) VALUES (?,?)"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

//bind parameters: $awb will be the AWBNoSeries values, $genRequestDT will be the AWBNoGenRequestedDateTime (same for all AWBNoSeries values)
if (!$stmt->bind_param("is", $awb, $genRequestDT)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

//set $genRequestDT equal to AWBNoGenRequestedDateTime value to be inserted with each record (this only needs to be done once)
$genRequestDT = $parsedData['AWBNoGenRequestedDateTime'];

//loop through AWBNoSeries values and insert each one into the db
foreach ($parsedData['AWBNoSeries'] as $awb){
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
}

$stmt->close(); //close the statement

// justin code end

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks , can you please guide me what i need to pass inside values in `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ecomexpress_awb(awb) VALUES (?)"); `

Comment: Nothing, it should be correct as-is :). In your code, just replace this: `$sql = $con->query('INSERT INTO ecomexpress_awb(awb) values ()'); ` with the code provided.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your [code as here](https://pastebin.com/P1hntnXS) & got result as in [justin.php](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/justin.php) , what wrong i did ?

Comment: you can even try this . $obj=json_decode($obj);
$allvalues='';
foreach($obj->AWBNoSeries as $values){
 $allvalues .='('.$values.'),';
}
$allvalues=substr($allvalues,0,-1);

and in you code replace 
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO ecomexpress_awb(awb) values $allvalues");

Comment: @vickeycolors, Sorry about that, I did not notice you used `$con` as your `mysqli` connection variable. I have updated my code, please give the updated code a try...

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha sorry, no i got result as in the [link](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/shah.php) error 1 : Trying to get property of non-object in error 2 : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query()

Comment: @JustinT. sorry for delay , column name is `created_at`

Answer (score 1):

How to insert `curl` response **JSON** values into a database:

```
  <?php
$hostname = "localhost";      // That Is For Database Connection
$database = "demo";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die('Could not select database');
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();                     // That Is For Curl
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
$url = "http://socialinfotech.in/development/jsondemo/category.json";  // Pass Your json Url
$data = get_data($url);
$data_json = json_decode($data, true);  // For Decord Your Json Value
foreach ($data_json['Result'] as $key => $value) {        // Foreach Because Multiple Values

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `demo`.`category` (category_id, category_name, category_image) 
   VALUES ('" . $value['category_id'] . "', '" . $value['category_name'] . "', '" . $value['category_image'] . "')");

foreach ($value['card'] as $keys => $values) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `demo`.`card` (ref_category_id,  card_image, user_name, user_image) 
   VALUES ('" . $value['category_id'] . "','" . $values['card_image'] . "', '" .$values['user_name']. "', '" .$values['user_image']. "')");
}
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<h1>Check Your Database Value</h1>
</body>
```

That Is My Json Value
[image: Json Value]

And That Is My Insert Value In Database
[image: Insert Value In Database]